# In which folder do I store audio files so as to load it as fast as possible for text to speech conversion ?

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

I am developing and android app for text to speech conversion for regional language and for that I am storing basic audio sounds for pronunciation of words. Whenever a character is read from file the corresponding audio file is chosen for waveform generation. hence a single audio file is fetched so many times even for small amount of content in file. So here my question is where I'll have to store that audio files such that loading can be as fast as possible?

Comment: `Whenever a character is read from file` Why would you read characters from file? This is about speach wasn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What folder its in won't make a real difference, so long as you unpack it from assets (assets being compressed).  What would make a difference is storing it in memory vs on disk.  Of course that depends on how many/how big of sound files you actually use-  do you have one per word, one per phoneme, or something else?  My guess is you'll actually have better performance if you combine multiple phonemes into a single waveform for playback rather than try to play each individually.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do. Waveform generation using phonemes. But I don't know how. I would appreciate your help.